# insertRule and addRule

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet, css-animations

On a site that I'm developing I have to create rules to the css on the go, but for some reason
insertRule and addRule do not want to work.

Here's the code:

```
function change(anim, fromValue, toValue) {
    // find our -webkit-keyframe rule
    var keyframes = findKeyframesRule(anim);

    // remove the existing 0% and 100% rules
    keyframes.deleteRule("0%");
    keyframes.deleteRule("100%");

    if(keyframes.insertRule){
        // create new 0% and 100% rules with random numbers
        keyframes.insertRule("0% {background-position: " + fromValue + ";}");
        keyframes.insertRule("100% {background-position: " + toValue + ";}");
    }else{
        keyframes.addRule("0%","{background-position:" +fromValue+";}",0);
        keyframes.addRule("100%","{background-position:" +fromValue+";}",1);
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that firefox is able to go through the deleteRule but when it gets to insertRule and addRule it just doesn't work. Also the code does work in chrome so I'm inclined to believe that I might just be missing something small.

EDIT:
Upon debugging it seems that the function isn't even defined, but deleteRule is. Any ideas now?

Comment: I think [Firefox uses a different API for keyframe rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframesRule).

Comment: Like Pointy said, use `appendRule`

Comment: Yup that's definitely it.

Comment: This issue looks like it was [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460710/insertrule-and-addrule#comment32386255_21460710) when Pointy pointed out that the `insertRule()` and `deleteRule()` methods will not work for CSS animations, and require the use of a different API.